# Check if only some values are not empy in array?

Tags: php, arrays, isnullorempty

I have some array like this:-

```
$atts = [
    "images_url" => "1",
    "link_list" => "2",
];
```

But sometimes array can be like this:-

```
$atts = [
    "images_url" => "1"
];
```

Or first can be empty based is it not empty i need some extra logic, how to check if some value of array is not empty or exist and do some extra logic?

Comment: Are you familiar with `isset()`?

Comment: Tried issset, and tried empty and so no luck :(

Comment: Take a look at `array_diff` function, maybe combine it with `array_filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like below:-

```
if(count($atts) > count(array_filter($atts))){
  echo "some indexes are empty";
}
```

Example:-https://eval.in/728563

For your another question in comment

```
foreach($atts as $key=>$val){
   if(!empty($atts[$key])){ // will check both index exist and have some value
      echo $val;
   }
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/728568

Comment: Sometimes I have that value sometimes i dont, but i need to check somehow

Comment: I have edited my question sorry, if there no value that key does not exist

Comment: @MiomirDancevic  check answer again. 2nd part